# Extract the data from array_buffer and stored in the variable

Tags: c, gps, microcontroller

I am receiving data continuously using UART and stored in the buffer in the following form::

```
 $GNRMC,114811.00,A,3558.94849,N,14008.90158,E,0.076,,141115,,,A*69
 $GNVTG,,T,,M,0.076,N,0.141,K,A*38
 $GNGSA,A,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,3.03,1.18,2.80*1E
 $GPGSV,3,2,09,20,04,163,,22,49,280,29,24,45,048,33,25,53,183,28*75
 $GNGLL,3558.94849,N,14008.90158,E,114811.00,A,A*70*
```

I want to extract only the `$GNRMC`data and store it on some variable  `year, mon, day, hour, min, sec` so that I can display that in 16*2LCD. The value right after $GNRMC `114811` is the time. But I am not getting the data on those variables. Where I am wrong?

```
void gps_getinfo(unsigned char rx2_id_buff[]);
void uart2_rx_int(void);
#define MAX_LINEBUF 70
char gps_linebuf[MAX_LINEBUF];
unsigned char time_flag;
unsigned char rx2_id_buff[70];  
unsigned char rx2_id_pointer;   
unsigned char year[4]={0},mon[4]={0},day[4]={0};
unsigned char hour[4]={0},min[4]={0},sec[4]={0};
#pragma interrupt uart2_rx_int  (vect=0x16)

void uart2_rx_int(void)
{
    unsigned char error;
    error = SSR11 & 0x07;                                                  
    rx2_id = SDR11;                                                  
    if (error == 0) {   
        if(rx2_id ==  '$' ) rx2_id_pointer = 0;    
             rx2_id_buff[rx2_id_pointer] = rx2_id;        //storing data in the buffer received form UART                      
             gps_getinfo(rx2_id_buff[rx2_id_pointer]);                                         
          }
        else    
             rx2_id_buff[rx2_id_pointer] = err | 0xF0;
             rx2_id_pointer++;                                        
        if (rx2_id_pointer > 69) rx2_id_pointer = 0;
}

void gps_getinfo(unsigned char rx2_id_buff[]) {
    short i,j,len;
    char *ptr,*ptrTop;
    unsigned char j1,j2;
    unsigned char comma[20]={0};    
    
    if (rx2_id_buff != '\n') {      
        gps_linebuf[idx++] = rx2_id_buff;                                           
        if(idx >= MAX_LINEBUF)idx=0;
    }
    else {
        gps_linebuf[idx++] = '\n';
        gps_linebuf[idx] = '\0';        
        i = MAX_LINEBUF;
        j = idx - 1;
        while(1) {
            if(gps_linebuf[j] == '$') break;                         
            j--;
            if(j < 0) j = MAX_LINEBUF - 1;
            if(i-- == 0) {
                gps_linebuf[0] = 0; idx=0;
                return;
            }
        }
        gps_linebuf[idx] = 0; idx=0;                                     
        ptrTop = (char *)&gps_linebuf[j];
        ptr = (char *)&gps_linebuf[j];
        //$GNRMC,114811.00,A,3558.94849,N,14008.90158,E,0.076,,141115,,,A*69
        if(strstr(ptrTop,"GNRMC")!=0) {
            len=strlen(ptr);
            j=0;
            for(i=0; i<len; ++i,ptr++) {                   
                if(*ptr == ',') {
                    comma[j++] = i+1;
                }
            }
            ptr = ptrTop;
            j1=comma[0];
            j2=comma[1] - comma[0];
            time_flag = 0;
            if(j2>=4) {
                strncpy((char *)hour,ptr+j1  ,2);                                   
                strncpy((char *)min, ptr+j1+2,2);                        
                strncpy((char *)sec, ptr+j1+4,2);                           
                time_flag |=0x01;
            }
            j1=comma[1];
            j2=comma[2] - comma[1];
            if(j2>=1) {
                if(*(ptr + j1) == 'A') {
                    time_flag |=0x04;
                }
            }
            j1=comma[8];
            j2=comma[9] - comma[8];
            if(j2>=4) {
                strncpy((char *)day,  ptr+j1  ,2);                                      
                strncpy((char *)mon,  ptr+j1+2,2);                                 
                strncpy((char *)year, ptr+j1+4,2);                                  
                time_flag |=0x02;
                year = atoi((char *)year);                
                mon  = atoi((char *)mon);                  
                day  = atoi((char *)day);               
                hour = atoi((char *)hour);              
                min  = atoi((char *)min);               
                sec  = atoi((char *)sec);                           
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This line is wrong: `if (rx2_id_buff != '\n') {`. You are comparing a char pointer with a char.

Comment: This too: `gps_linebuf[idx++] = rx2_id_buff;`  Assigning one position in a char array to a pointer.

Comment: How should I compare? Could u please help?

Comment: What is `idx`?  It is not declared in your code, so your code is incomplete.

Comment: I would recommend you check how many commas you found (`j`) so you have at least the amount you are presuming. And since you're always copying 6 chars, just compare with 6: `if (j2 == 6) {`.  Do you have access to a console so you can add debugging prints? Or just a debugger?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few errors in your code.  I have tested it, and with some smaller changes it works as expected.

Add the correct header files:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Please change

```
if (rx2_id_buff != '\n') {
    gps_linebuf[idx++] = rx2_id_buff;
```

to

```
if (rx2_id_buff[0] != '\n') {
    gps_linebuf[idx++] = rx2_id_buff[0];
```

The integer output variables need to have different names than the corresponding string variables:

```
int i_year,i_mon,i_day;
int i_hour,i_min,i_sec;

i_year = atoi((char *)year);
i_mon  = atoi((char *)mon);
i_day  = atoi((char *)day);
i_hour = atoi((char *)hour);
i_min  = atoi((char *)min);
i_sec  = atoi((char *)sec);
```